# Offline and online server processes code differently

Tags: php, arrays

I have a piece of code that get's processed differently on my localhost and live server.

I have no idea why or what to change.

Here is the piece of code:

```
for($k = 0; $k < count($data['SurveyAnswer']); $k++) {
    if(isset($data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['number'])) {
        if($data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['number'] != '')
            $data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer'] = $data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['number'].','.$data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['text'];
        else
            $data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer'] = '';
        } else if(isset($data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['yn'])) {
    if($data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['yn'] == 'No')
        $data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer'] = 'No,' . $data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['text'];
    else
        $data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer'] = 'Yes';
    } else if(isset($data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['scale'])) {
        $data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer'] = $data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['scale'] . ',' . $data['SurveyAnswer'][$k]['answer']['text'];
    }
}
```

For arguments sake, this is the data:

```
data = array(
    'SurveyAnswer' => array(
        0 => array (
            'answer' => array(
                'number' => '4',
                'text' => 'Test text'
            ),
        1 => array (
            'answer' => array(
                'number' => '',
                'text' => ''
            ),
        2 => array (
            'answer' => array(
                'yn' => 'No',
                'text' => 'Test text'
            ),
        3 => array (
            'answer' => array(
                'yn' => 'Yes',
                'text' => ''
            ),
        4 => array (
            'answer' => array(
                'scale' => 'Good',
                'text' => 'Testing text'
            )
        ),
        5 => array (
            'answer' => '3'
        )
    )
);
```

This is how my **localhost** changes the data (PHP version 5.4.7 on Windows):

```
data = array(
    'SurveyAnswer' => array(
        0 => array (
            'answer' => '4,Test text'
            ),
        1 => array (
            'answer' => ''
            ),
        2 => array (
            'answer' => 'No,Test text'
            ),
        3 => array (
            'answer' => 'Yes'
            ),
        4 => array (
            'answer' => 'Good,Testing text'
            )
        ),
        5 => array (
            'answer' => '3'
        )
    )
);
```

And this is how my **live server** changes the data (PHP version 5.3.23 on CentOS):

```
data = array(
    'SurveyAnswer' => array(
        0 => array (
            'answer' => '4,4'
            ),
        1 => array (
            'answer' => ''
            ),
        2 => array (
            'answer' => 'T,T'
            ),
        3 => array (
            'answer' => 'Yes'
            ),
        4 => array (
            'answer' => 'T,T'
            )
        ),
        5 => array (
            'answer' => '3'
        )
    )
);
```

Can it be the version difference causing the issue or is there something else.

**UPDATE**

Real world data, got this with a CakePHP debug before and CakePHP debug after the code:

**localhost**

```
\app\Controller\SurveyAnswersController.php (line 51) (BEFORE)
array(
    'SurveyAnswer' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'answer' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'answer' => '2'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'answer' => '3'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'answer' => array(
                'number' => '3',
                'text' => 'asdfasdfasdf'
            )
        )
    )
)

\app\Controller\SurveyAnswersController.php (line 67) (AFTER)
array(
    'SurveyAnswer' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'answer' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'answer' => '2'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'answer' => '3'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'answer' => '3,asdfasdfasdf'
        )
    )
)
```

**webserver**

```
/app/Controller/SurveyAnswersController.php (line 51) (BEFORE)
array(
    'SurveyAnswer' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'answer' => '1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'answer' => '2'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'answer' => '3'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'answer' => array(
                'number' => '3',
                'text' => 'asdfasdfasdf'
            )
        )
    )
)

app/Controller/SurveyAnswersController.php (line 67) (AFTER)
array(
    'SurveyAnswer' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'answer' => '1,1'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'answer' => '2,2'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'answer' => '3,3'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'answer' => '3,asdfasdfasdf'
        ),
    )
)
```

I shortened the data as it's around 100 questions.

Comment: are you sure that your data is not corrupted somewhere else?

Comment: Yes I am sure. It only gets changed when I upload it. I've uploaded all controllers and models associated with this feature, and it still does it.

Comment: Your data looks odd. Either at least a closing bracket is missing between for example SurveyAnswer[1] and [2], or something else is afoot. Post a var_export of the actual data your using.

Comment: Question has been updated. I'm updating my PHP installation to the latest version as we speak. Hopefully that solves the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, but it was a version issue. Updated my PHP to 5.4.x and it worked.